# Automatically generating accounts or magic links for users to register for Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C directory configured for users to register with their emails and access some resources using an id_token from logging in.

My issue now is that I need to be able to manually add users (ideally by email address) and send them a magic link they can click on to be auto-registered by azure and only have to put in a password/other sign up information.

As a start I tried to add users via the 'new user' option in the 'All Users' blade in Azure AD B2C however interestingly I found new users cannot have a none-federated email address (i.e. someperson@gmail.com) but someperson@gmail.com can sign up and be added to the Azure AD B2C directory so I'm obviously missing something here (or there's an issue with Azure AD B2C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a local account, with any email address, using the Azure AD B2C portal. You can only create a work account, with the *tenant*.onmicrosoft.com domain, using this portal. You must create a local account [using the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

You can implement the activation flow using a custom policy.

[The Wingtip sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c) implements an activation flow as follows:

- A backend system [creates a local account](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipToysWebApplication/Controllers/UserController.cs#L58), with an email address and a random password, using the Azure AD Graph API.
- The backend system [generates an activation link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipToysWebApplication/Controllers/UserController.cs#L81) and then sends this link to the email recipient.
- The email recipient opens the activation link.
- A frontend system [validates the activation link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/ActivationController.cs#L35) and, if valid, then [invokes an activation policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/ActivationController.cs#L54) and [passes a signed token](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Startup.cs#L429) containing the email address to be "signed up".
- [The activation policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_activation.xml), which is a custom policy that invokes [an activation user journey](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L3081), then prompts the end user to set their new password (and, optionally, other profile information).

Comment: This is very helpful.
Once the activation link has been validated, do you need to invoke an activation policy (e.g. for the user to set their new password)?
Could the user just use their randomly generated password for subsequent authentications and set/reset their password later on if they want to?

Comment: On the https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/Demo there is no option to sign up with a magic link (activation link). It is only possible to log in with code by email. Is there any sample for signup/sign-in with a magic link?